# Create sf points and then lines from 4 columns in a data.frame while staying in dplyr

Tags: r, point, line, sf

So I have a `data.frame` like this:

```r
df = data.frame(
  x1 = runif(10, 10,11), 
  y1 = runif(10, 47,48),
  y2 = runif(10, 11,12), 
  y2 = runif(10, 48,49),
  name = sample(letters, 10))
```

And I want to create a `sf dataframe` that containes the lines from the points `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)`.

I fail at two stages.

- First I am not entirely sure how to use `st_point()` in e.g. a `dplyr::mutate`
- And I also do not know how to then convert it to a linestring

My imaginary pseudo code would look something like this:

```r
# does not work  
df = data.frame(
  x1 = runif(10, 10,11), 
  y1 = runif(10, 47,48),
  y2 = runif(10, 11,12), 
  y2 = runif(10, 48,49),
  name = sample(letters, 10)) %>% 
  mutate( # create the points
    pt1 = st_point(c(x1, y1)),
    pt2 = st_point(c(x2, y2))
  ) %>% # create the lines
  mutate(
    line = st_linestring(pt1, pt2)
  )
```

Of course this does not work. But maybe someone has an idea on how to make this work.

Comment: Are the duplicated column names in you `df` intentional or mistakes? You've got two `y2` columns (which get renamed, but it still looks wrong...).

Comment: If you read the help for st_linestring you'll see it needs a matrix, not points, so make a matrix from the points and feed that to st_linestring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd skip the `dplyr` and write it as a function, making building blocks that I can test:

```
make_line <- function(xy2){
    st_linestring(matrix(xy2, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))
}

make_lines <- function(df, names=c("x1","y1","x2","y2")){
    m = as.matrix(df[,names])
    lines = apply(m, 1, make_line, simplify=FALSE)
    st_sfc(lines)
}

sf_pts_to_lines <- function(df, names=c("x1","y1","x2","y2")){
    geom = make_lines(df, names)
    df = st_sf(df, geometry=geom)
    df
}
```

Then I do:

```
df = sf_pts_to_lines(df)
```

You could if you wanted put that in a pipeline:

```
df = df %>% sf_pts_to_lines %>% ....
```

But doing things a line at a time in small chunks that you can easily test by checking intermediate results can be a much easier way to solve problems, and is generally faster than when R has to work round your pipe syntax.

Note that if you do it on a data frame that already has geometry, you need to drop the geometry first:

```
df = sf_pts_to_lines(st_drop_geometry(df))
```

Comment: As always, thank you so so much! And also similar to all your other answers: I need some time so go through this one;) I solved it while staying in dplyr. However, it feels somewhat strange